# C macro with syslog logging

Tags: c, macros

How can I replace this

```
syslog("some text");
```

with this, using C macro

```
if (debug)
    syslog (LOG_DEBUG, "Function %s Line %d File %s Text %s", __func__, __LINE__, __FILE__,"some text");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#define syslog(text)     \
do {                     \
  if(debug)              \
     syslog (LOG_DEBUG, "Function %s Line %d File %s Text %s", __func__, __LINE__, __FILE__, text);  \
} while(0)
```

If `debug` is defined somewhere you can eliminate the `if` branch:

```
#ifdef debug
#define syslog(text)  syslog (LOG_DEBUG, "Function %s Line %d File %s Text %s", __func__, __LINE__, __FILE__, text); 
#else
#define syslog(text)
#endif
```

Answer (score 4):

The do..while(0) trick handles the compound 'if' statement, but syslog() is printf-like, and can take a variable number of arguments.  We need a couple of tricks from the gcc preprocessor to handle this.

First, macros with variable numbers of arguments are supported, using the '...' notation.
We can use this to put our own text between the format string and the variable list. However, there is a catch: what if there is no variable list?  In that case we use a special meaning of the ## operator for just this situation to eat the extra ','.

```
#define syslog(fmt, args...)    \
do { \
    if (debug) \
        syslog(LOG_DEBUG, "Func %s Line %d file %s text " fmt, __func__, __LINE__, __FILE__, ##args); \
} while (0)
```

This expands these:

```
syslog("string");
syslog("format %d", value);
if (value)
syslog("something %d more %s", little, "complicated");
```

into this:

```
do { if (debug) syslog(LOG_DEBUG, "Func %s Line %d file %s text " "string", __func__, 8, "tp.c"); } while (0);

do { if (debug) syslog(LOG_DEBUG, "Func %s Line %d file %s text " "format %d", __func__, 10, "tp.c", value); } while (0);

if (value)
   do { if (debug) syslog(LOG_DEBUG, "Func %s Line %d file %s text " "something %d more %s", __func__, 13, "tp.c", little, "complicated"); } while (0);
```